# Error in website deployed in VM with Nginx

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx

I'm new developing.

I have an issue, I'm deploying my app to an VM and I'm using Nginx, after I deployed it I go to the url and I see the website but I see this error in the network tab:

https://i.postimg.cc/VN4L74D8/Captura.png

I think maybe I need to add something to nginx, but actually I don't know.

Comment: have you setup ssl? your links/assets are being accessed over https

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem